# Scanning DynamoDB for items WITHOUT a specific attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Table with multiple items some of which do not have a specific attribute. Now I want to scan the table for exactly these items.

I'm using the JavaScript SDK from AWS.

I've tried lots of different variations, which I mainly took from the AWS documentation and some google results.

The best I've come up with is this:
(And it returns all of the items disregarding the condition)

```js
const params = {
  TableName: curTableName,
  IndexName: "THE_number-index",
  ScanFilter: {
  "THE_number": {
   ComparisonOperator: "NULL"
  }
    }
};
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

What are the correct parameters for the scan() call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably best to use `FilterExpression` instead of `ScanFilter`.

There is a function called `attribute_exists()` which I think is what you're looking for.

[Scan request docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#API_Scan_RequestSyntax)

[Condition expression docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference.Functions)

Also, check out [this example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sweet-treats-for-dynamodb-users/) - about 3/4 of the way down the page: `SQL-Like Expressions`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Steven S. answer, I've found a solution for the params:

```js
const params = {
       TableName: curTableName,
       ProjectionExpression: "Id,THE_number",
       FilterExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(THE_number)'
      };

dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```